# Graying Out a QPixmap

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to figure how with I can take a QPixmap and make it appear 'grayed out'... basically, remove all color and lower the alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QGraphicsColorizeEffect`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicscolorizeeffect.html) is probably a more preferred way going forward.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use something like this to set the alpha?

```
QPixmap &setAlpha(QPixmap &px, int val){
  QPixmap alpha = px;
  QPainter p(&alpha);
  p.fillRect(alpha.rect(), QColor(val, val, val));
  p.end();
  px.setAlphaChannel(alpha);
  return px;
}
```

You may need to convert to a [QImage](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#toImage) and use [convertToFormat](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#convertToFormat)() to conveniently convert to greyscale.

Comment: Just FYI: setAlphaChannel() has been deprecated and is only available in Qt3 support. http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap-qt3.html

Answer (score 2):

A desaturation algorithm (removing all color) would involve iterating over every pixel and normalizing the RGB values.

The pseudocode looks like this:

```
foreach pixel in image.bits() {

   int grayColor = 0.299f * pixel.red +
                    0.587f * pixel.green +
                    0.114f * pixel.blue ;

   image.putPixel(grayColor);
}
```